# after a long time that i am using git i get this error "No valid git object identified by 'HEAD' exists in the repository" before i do 'commit'

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

I use GIT For a while. two days ago I did 'commit' and everything went smoothly. Since then I added and changed a few things, and now when I try to do 'commit' I get the following error:

"An error occurred. Detailed message: No valid git object identified by 'HEAD' exists in the repository. "

I do not know if this is related, but by mistake before I did 'commit' I wanted to make a copy of the folder on the desktop but instead I started to move the original folder to the desktop. When I realized what I had done I canceled it and didn't see any change in the code.
Maybe it changed the settings of Git? If so, where can I see it and how can I fix it?

I checked the connect to the team project and its connect. 
Also I checked the git setting - my userName and Email and defult location are right.

thanks.

Comment: Please, run `git fsck` in your repository and post the output here. See the content of `.git/` too.

Comment: how i do that?  I don't find the repository, and I also don't find the  project’s directory (from web search I realized that they are related). 
My professor wanted us to use GIT but not really taught us how to do it right. So I use it for a long time but did not really know much about it.

Comment: Well, at this point I guess you have to read some tutorial/manual. No one can help you if you don't know what "repository" means.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the `branch` pointed to by `HEAD (.git/HEAD)` is not included inside the `.git/refs/heads` folder. Open the `HEAD` file with `notepad` and change the content to `ref: refs/heads/master`. Obviously you first need to find the local repository.